# How can I find the actual height of a div without jQuery when it has a max-height property set in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to find the height of a div using the `offsetHeight` property of the HTMLElement.

It is consistently returning the height that is specified by max-height, even if there isn't enough text to take up that amount of space (it doesn't on screen).

Is there a way around this without using jQuery? I'm using Angular 2

```css
.ra-card-overview__text--collapsed {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  min-height: 0px;
  max-height: 4rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="overview" [ngClass]="{
  'ra-card-overview__text--collapsed': hiddenOverviewClass,
  'ra-card-overview__text--expanded': !hiddenOverviewClass}">
  {{RA.Overview}}
</div>
```

```js
this.overviewHeight = document.getElementById('overview').offsetHeight;
```

This always returns 64.

Comment: height is not a property of an HTMLElement object

Comment: try this document.getElementById('overview').clientHeight ;

Comment: `window.getComputedStyle(element).height`

Comment: Why not just do `$(".ra-card-overview__text--collapsed").height();` ?

Comment: @RalphDavidAbernathy - What part of "without using JQuery" did you not get?

Comment: @Nitin none of offsetHeight, clientHeight, and scrollHeight return the right value

Comment: @Alohci I added the HTML just now, if you still can't reproduce perhaps it's an inheritance problem?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://jsfiddle.net/cvtdbgb4/)

Comment: @Alohci completely missed that, my bad.